# What is the specific meaning of the term "module" in app development?

Tags: java, android, module, terminology

I am new at android app development and I want to participate an app development contest. For this I have to do a registration. Now I am facing a problem about a word “module”. I am confused what exactly module in app development is? These words are provided in my registration form.

> Describe your app idea from top to bottom
>   Please describe your app
>   idea from what modules might be required, how data will be managed,
>   what interfaces might be needed etc. You can also host your file on
>   dropbox , Google drive and provide us link of your file here.

What should I write now? 
Please help me. Sorry for bad English and Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to be a question of definition. So it would be the next logic step to ask the person/organisation that use the term what **their** understanding is instead of asking a bunch of strangers on the web without linking the respective source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(1) In software, a module is a part of a program. Programs are composed of one or more independently developed modules that are not combined until the program is linked. A single module can contain one or several routines.

from [here](http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/M/module.html).

Basically if you are developing a program you need to separate it's parts by their functions.
Let's say it is a post office: you need a module which process the incoming messages (classes for filtering, checking the stamp, etc), a computation module (classes deciding which district it's going or is it going to another post office, etc), and a delivering module (postmans to streets or cars to another post offices). These parts are complex but they have their well-defined job and they should work independently and only communicating thorough their well-defined interfaces.

Of course this example is very basic and unrealistic but I hope you get the point.